# Understand summernote upload image

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, base64, summernote

I'm using Summernote Editor with Bootstrap 3.0 and i'm trying to understand how summernote can upload my image without saving in a folder.

See a peace of my source code generated by Summernote:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><br></p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD//gATQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIEdJTVD/2wBDAAUDBAQEAwUEBAQFBQUGBwwIBwcHBw8LCwkMEQ8SEhEPERETFhwXExQaFRERGCEYGh0dHx8fExciJCIeJBweHx7/2wBDAQUFBQcGBw4ICA4eFBEUHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh7/wAARCAKGBQ4DASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHQABAAMAAwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAUGBwMECAIBCf....
```

I imagine that base64 serialize my image in a String, and when i need see this image the unserialize is called.

1 - What is the positive and negative points for this process ? 
2 - My ideia is right ? The image in serialized with base64 algorithm ?